# I get the error "no main manifest attribute", when compiling and running a simple program in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Here's the program

```
data class Resultado (val resultado: Int, val tesoro: Boolean)

fun main() {
        val busca =  fun(intento: Int): Resultado
        {
                val cosas = listOf( 3, 33, 333, 42, 1, 1, 111 )
                if ( intento == 4  ) {
                        return Resultado( 42, true )
                } else {
                        return Resultado( cosas[intento], false )
                }
        }

        val (valor1, premio1) = busca( 2 )
        println( "2 devuelve " + valor1 + " y tiene premio " + premio1  )
        val (valor2, premio2) = busca( 4 )
        println( "4 devuelve " + valor2 + " y tiene premio " + premio2  )

}
```

It [compiles](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) correctly either directly or with

```
kotlinc code/tesoro.kt -include-runtime -d tesoro.jar
```

Leaving all kind of files in the directory:

```
ls *.class *.jar
Resultado.class  tesoro.jar  TesoroKt.class  TesoroKt$main$busca$1.class
```

However, it does not run

```
java -jar tesoro.jar 
no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en tesoro.jar
```

Which means pretty much as said above, "No main manifest attribute". This is

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Kotlin version is 1.1.3-2

Is the program missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use the latest stable version. With kotlinc 1.3.31 it works correctly, also with `fun main()` in place.

Comment: First, does that mean Kotlin documents are wrong? Or simply no one uses it from the command line? Second, doing what you say I get a different error: `Error: no se ha encontrado el método principal en la clase TesoroKt, defina el método principal del siguiente modo:\n   public static void main(String[] args)\nde lo contrario, se deberá ampliar una clase de aplicación JavaFX javafx.application.Application` which is in Spanish, but you get the idea...

Comment: no... the documentation is right here... it was me who was wrong ;-) but it should work with version 1.3.31...

Comment: This one is 1.1.3. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: ah, well... the parameterless main is only available since version 1.3 ;-) your IDE most probably has the latest stable version... and compilation also succeeds, because then it's just a regular function... but you do not have your fully functional `main(args)` then :-)

Comment: good error messages are not sufficiently appreciated in the programming language development community :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the definition of the function `main` which causes this error in version 1.1.3. It should be:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
```

It will yield that LTA error if it's not, so you need to include it even if you will not be using the arguments.

Comment: which version do you use? With kotlinc 1.3.31 it builds the correct self-contained jar for me... and therefore runs...